# How to restart spring boot application when Hikari give connection timeout?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot-actuator

We have spring boot application & getting below exception. Solution for that is **only spring boot application restart.**

Question 1 : How I come to know that I am getting below exception and now need application restart?

Question 2 : How to restart the spring boot application ?

**Exception:**

**Failed to obtain JDBC connection ; nested exception is a java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException:HikariPool-1**

Comment: Use transactions, enable validation on idle connections and make sure you aren't messing around with connections yourself (as that will, when done wrong, lead to connection leaks).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=500
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=20
spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=3000
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=60000
```

and if you only want to restart kill the tomcat server you can use this command:

```
sudo kill -9 `sudo lsof -t -i:8080`
```

Comment: and if you are using queries like updating or transaction-based functions. try to use @Transactional annotation on your function.

Comment: No Mayank ,this will not work. I want to manually restart the whole application when some exception is come. The solution which you said that is related to hikari . How this configuration restart the springboot application when i get any exception . where I need to specify the exception . Could you please help me in this? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow configuration worked for me so don't need to restart also . Thanks everyone for your help.

spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout = 600000

spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size = 15

spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000